# Making methods of a class as a friend

Tags: c++, friend

I would like to make a method of a class as friend instead of making the whole class friend.
Here is what I have

```
class tar;
class foo
{
private:
    int foo_int;
public:
    foo(){std::cout << "Constructor\n";}
    friend void tar::anotherMethod();
};

class tar
{
    public:
    void anotherMethod()
    {
        foo f;      
        f.foo_int = 13;
        std::cout << f.foo_int;
    }

};
```

These are the errors i get

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'tar'
error C2248: 'foo::foo_int' : cannot access private member declared in class 'foo'
```

Any suggestions on what i might be doing wrong ?

Comment: [C2027](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c2dk0ah.aspx): `A type cannot be used until it is defined. To resolve the error, be sure the type is fully defined before referencing it.`.

Comment: I declared `class tar` as a prototype. I cant understand why its not being picked

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095071/incomplete-type-in-nested-name-specifier) explains it a little better.

Comment: Make the whole class friend to avoid headaches.

Comment: I know i could do that But i was experimenting with making a method friend only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other to make your code compile, you can rearrange the declaration and definitions:

```
#include <iostream>

class tar
{
    public:
    void anotherMethod();
};

class foo
{
private:
    int foo_int;
public:
    foo(){std::cout << "Constructor\n";}
    friend void tar::anotherMethod();
};

void tar::anotherMethod()
{
    foo f;      
    f.foo_int = 13;
    std::cout << f.foo_int;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I understand that you rearranged this to get the type recognized. I am confused as to why the compiler is fine with the type when I replace `friend void tar::anotherMethod();` with `friend class tar`

Comment: @MistyD: Because it knows that `tar` is a class (you declared it before), but it does not know whether there would be a member `tar::anotherMethod()` until it sees the definition of the member function.