# Incomplete type used in nested namespace

Tags: c++

Below code gives me:

> In member function ‘void A::method()’:error: incomplete type ‘B’ used
>   in nested name specifier B::meth();

I searched for solution to this error on SO found that I could use `::` but didnt help

```
class B;
class A
{
    public:
    void method()
    {
        B::meth();
    }
};

class B
{
    public:
    void static meth()
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried defining class B before class A?

Comment: I have but then I have other dependencies problem, is there any other solution ?

Comment: Take a look at @R Sahu's answer hope it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incomplete type in nested name specifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095071/incomplete-type-in-nested-name-specifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the line `A::method` is defined, `B` is known only by name, not by its full definition.

You have to make sure that the full definition of `B` is known before you can use `B::meth()`.

**Option 1**

Move the definition of `B` before the definition of `A`.

```
class B
{
    public:
    void static meth()
    {
    }
};

class A
{
    public:
    void method()
    {
        B::meth();
    }
};
```

**Option 2**

Move the definition of `A::method` after the definition of `B`.

```
class A
{
    public:
    void method();
};

class B
{
    public:
    void static meth()
    {
    }
};

void A::method()
{
   B::meth();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that class A is trying to access a member of class B before class B is defined. You should define class B first. Furthermore, consider renaming the classes so that they will be in alphabetical order.